# nodejs program not work in hosted website. works well in localhost

Tags: node.js

A simple Node.js program server.js
It works well in localhost.
But once move into a hosted website environment, it does not work.
Node.js program server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var port = 8888;
var serverUrl = "localhost";
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  console.log("coming  ");
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  res.write("HI");
  res.end();
});
console.log("Listening at " + serverUrl + ":" + port);
server.listen(port, serverUrl);
```

It works well in localhost environment.
But once move into hosted account, it does not work.

```
var port = 8888;
var serverUrl = "www.mywebsite.com";
```

When go to www.mywebsite.com:8888, it says "`The connection time out`".
And there is no any message in nodejs console.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you leave out the host parameter in `server.listen`? I.e. try

```
server.listen(port);
```

instead of

```
server.listen(port, serverUrl);
```